# A simple probability problem - not sure about my computation

Tags: probability, random-variables

Here's a pretty simple problem:

> A factory produces 3 types of lamps, A, B, C. 30% of the lamps are of
>   type A, 30% B and the rest 40% C.  The lifetime of each type is
>   distributed exponentially, such that $\lambda_A$ for A, $\lambda_B$
>   for B and $\lambda_C$ for C.
>
> A lamp is considered to be valid if it's lifetime is more then $T$
>
> A lamp is randomly selected. What is the probability that it is valid?

What I thought is the following:

Let X be the selected lamp, and $T_Y, Y\in \{A,B,C\}$ be the RV that represents the lifespan of a lamp. Therefore:

$P($X is valid$)=P(X=A, T_A\geq T) + P(X=B, T_B\geq T) + P(X=C, T_C\geq T)$

Now I am confused. For example, if I look on one of the above events, for instance:$P(X=A, T_A\geq T)$

How can I compute it? I mean, how can I for instance tell if the events $\{X=A\}$ and $\{T_A\geq T\}$ without any extra information? if they're not independent, how can I compute that?

Comment: This is an interesting question.  I think that the answer is that we're trying to use probability theory to make some statement about the world, and that we have assumptions about the world built in.  In the instant case, we don't believe that the process of selecting a lamp has any effect on the lifetime of the lamp.  The lifetimes are fixed in advance, and don't change.  In the same way, in all those problems about picking colored balls from urns, we never consider the possibility that the color of the ball changes when we pick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula:

$P($ x is valid $ ) =  P(X=A, T_A\geq T) + P(X=B, T_B\geq T) + P(X=C, T_C\geq T)$

is not exactly what you are looking for.

The correct formula would be :

P(x is  valid) = P(A was chosen) P(x is valid | A was chosen) + P(B was chosen) P(x is valid | B was chosen) + P(C was chosen)  P(x is valid | C was chosen)

Which gives:

$P( $ x  is  valid $ ) = \frac{3}{10} p(T_A \geq T) + \frac{3}{10} P(T_B \geq T ) + \frac{4}{10} P(T_c \geq T )$

This is because, if you know which lamp was chosen, you know exactly what the probability is that the lamp is valid, in terms of $\lambda$, because you know the way it is distributed.

The events "lamp A was chosen" and $T_A \sim exp(\lambda_A) $ are essentially the same.